# Missed comma between flow collection entries, how to fix?

Tags: yaml

I have this `yaml` definition and it gives the following error:

> missed comma between flow collection entries

This is how my `yaml` looks like:

```
 create_bucket_lifecycle_policy:
        action: aws_boto3.boto3action
        input:
          params:
            Bucket: <% $.bucket_full_name %>
            LifecycleConfiguration: {
                                      Rules: <-- this is where error coming
                                      - {'Expiration': {'Date': <%= format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y") %>}}             
                                    }
        on-success:
          - create_inline_policy
        on-error:
          - fail
```

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your YAML to the following:

```
create_bucket_lifecycle_policy:
        action: aws_boto3.boto3action
        input:
          params:
            Bucket: <% $.bucket_full_name %>
            LifecycleConfiguration:
                Rules: 
                  'Expiration': 
                      'Date': <%= format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y") %>
        on-success:
          - create_inline_policy
        on-error:
          - fail
```

I removed the braces as they are not required in YAML.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer would be more helpful if you described why your proposed solution works and/or what it does.